# Почтовая рассылка через отдельный серврер

Tags: php, email

Задача состоит в следующем:

- имеется сервер с работающем на нем сайтом
- есть отдельный почтовый сервер
- mx записи настроены

Вопрос, какие настройки нужно сделать (хотябы просто название, куда копать), чтобы отсылать письма кодом на сайте, а доходили до пользователей они с почтового сервера (с его ip адреса).

Вся информация, что находил, сводиться к тому, как поднять почтовый сервер, как настроить DKIM и пр., чтобы не попасть в спам. А вот именно как правильно настроить отправку, никак найти не могу.

Comment: Копайте в сторону отправка mail через smtp, Что-то типа: mail() через внешние SMTP (smtp.yandex.ru) для разных пользователей.

Comment: RifmaMan, спасибо большое. Разобрался.